# Start onscroll function when specific element is in viewport / not on topof the page - jsfiddle inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I made this parallax scrolling.

Using **tweenmax** library.

Right now scrolling is calculated for whole page, so by the time I reach parallax elements, they moved a lot, I need to start calculating scrolling only after parent **`#wrap`** comes to viewport.

**HTML :**

```html
<div class="asd"></div>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="scroll-parallax-1 a"></div>
  <div class="scroll-parallax-2 b"></div>
  <div class="scroll-parallax-3 c"></div>
  <div class="scroll-parallax-4 d"></div>
  <div class="scroll-parallax-5 e"></div>
</div>
```

**Script :**

```js
document.onscroll = function(){
  console.log(0.8*scrollY);
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-1", {y: 0.1*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-2", {y: 0.2*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-3", {y: 0.4*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-4", {y: 0.7*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-5", {y: 1.2*-scrollY });
}
```

**[Full jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7bt8rfk/)**

As you can see, by the time i #wrap comes to view, elements are already in the grey `.asd` div

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Martin. You're using a really old version of GSAP. This sort of thing is trivial using [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3/) and GSAP's official scroll plugin [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/). I highly recommend that you check them out. There's several parallax effects provided on [the ScrollTrigger docs page](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/).

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, i already used [https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll](Locomotive scroll) for this function, what do you think is better solution? That or GSAP3? It also has all kinds of triggers and animations etc

Comment: I did some reasearch and ScrollTrigger by GSAP works perfectly fine with Locomotive scroll, so it seems like that combination is the perfect solution. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: I wrote [an article about scrolling technologies](https://css-tricks.com/an-overview-of-scroll-technologies/) which has helpful charts at the bottom. I think ScrollTrigger is the best tool for scrolling (irrespective of the fact that I work for GreenSock) and if you need the smooth scrolling aspect then you can combine it with a library like Locomotive. GSAP 3 is *way* better than the older versions of GSAP.